# easy_install--failure to import

Tags: python, easy-install

I'm trying to learn web.py and I'm running into issues. I'm using Mac OSX Lion and what I'm doing is that I installed Python using Homebrew and then installed easy_install. I then did sudo easy_install web.py and it appeared to build correctly. However, when I run Python, I can't run "import web" because it can't find the module. I checked the web.py page and it says that if modules appear to install correctly but can't be imported then they're not going into /Library/Python/2.x/site-packages, but I definitely see web.py sitting there.

Any help on resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `import sys; print sys.path`. Do you see there the "/Library/Python/2.x/site-packages"?

Comment: That's strange; I see Homebrew's /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages. I'll follow the guide on custom install locations then.

Comment: Python documentation covers all kinds of module-installation options: http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-home-scheme. But I think a simpler solution for you is to create a symbolic link `ln -s /Library/Python/2.x/site-packages /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. You probably have installed the web.py as super-user so it wen to system-wide location, but for some reason when python is runned by your user it does not include that location.

Comment: Why did you install Python? OS X comes with it already.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I heard that installing packages and such is a massive pain on OS X.

Comment: Assuming you are starting the Python interpretor at the command line by typing ``% python``, what do you get when you do ``which python``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your /usr/local/bin/python set to the version in your cellar? If so, then

```
python setup.py install
```

should do the trick.

You could try creating a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin that points to the cellar. Example:

```
ln -s python  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/bin/python
```

I use homebrew on Mac OS X (10.5.8). And, that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I decided to nuke all of my Python (other than the system Python) and try again with Homebrew's latest one, and it worked.